# Display loading gif when I load a JSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have a JSP. When I call my JSP, it'll hit the database and displays the appropriate result. Coming to the point, since my JSP loads huge a value, it takes some time to load my page. So I need a loading gif while my page loads and that gif should disappear when my JSP fully loads. Can anyone help me by giving a sample code for this?

For example my code looks like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    Hello

    </body>
    </html>
```

So can anyone help me where to insert the loading gif code.

Comment: There is no code, it's just a GIF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two JSPs for this. The first one returns the "please wait" GIF plus some JavaScript that invokes the second JSP, possibly by [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

When the second JSP returns HTML, the JavaScript can then add that to the existing page.

You will want to use a JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. The documentation contains many examples how to send AJAX requests to a web server and process the results.